# How to add validations when form has checkboxes and anchor tag whose data-type is 'text'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have following cshtml code in which "tr" is parent tag,"td" is subtag and checkbox and anchor tags are inside "td" tag.the submit button control code is mentioned on the topline . It's in the following ways. Also, jquery code is mentioned below what I am looking for is when I select the checkbox and don't fill any data inside the textbox and click on submit then a validation message should arise 'please fill the description' in some kind of colour. Currently, the situation is when select checkbox then disabled button changes state to enabled but text control inside anchor tag if left not filled with any data and click on submit it is not generating warning message also each checkbox has its own anchor tag like there are multiple checkboxes in a row and each checkbox has there own anchor tag.

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="submitbtn">
    <button type="submit" id="submit 
     style="width:140px;height:30px;">Create 683</button>
  </div>
</div>
  @foreach (var item in Model.Items) /*-----to generate multiple rows-----*/
{
 @if (@currentItem != item.Item)
{
  <tr class="notifyAE-row  text-center">
  <td class="col-md-1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" id="chck" name="683radiobtn" 
  @*checked="checked"*@ />
 </td>
 </tr>
}
<tr class="class_@item.Item">
  <td class="col-md-2 ensuredoublespace text-left">
    @if (canAddEditItemsReqMet.Succeeded)
      {
       <a href="#" class="explanations" data-pk="@item.Item" data- 
type="text" data- 
         pendingItemId="@item.PendingItemId" data-name="@item.ValidItemBreakOutId" data- 
        compare683="@item.compare683" data-url="@Url.Action("UpdateExplanation", "Contract", new { 
        pendingItemId = item.PendingItemId, contractNo = Model.ContractNo, breakoutId = 
        item.ValidItemBreakOutId })">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Explanations)</a>
      }
      else
      {
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Explanations)
       
      }
 </td>
</tr>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
                $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $('#submit').prop("disabled", false);
                    } else {
                        {
                            if ($('.checks').filter(':checked').length < 1) {
                                $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

</script>
```

Comment: Please take the time to put enough code for us to understand what you are doing. What you've shown for HTML in invalid.

Comment: I hope now code is good enough from html side to understand

Comment: Where are your `form` and `table` tags?

Comment: It does not have form tag and table tag is not there foreach()loop is generating rows

Comment: If you are going to have `submit` buttons, then you need a `form` element for all the fields that collect the data that will be submitted to live inside of. Also, you can't have table rows and cells without the rows being children of a `table`.

Comment: What happening is actually when you click on <a> anchor tag it changes to textbox and then if this is textbox is left without anyvalue and checkbox is checked and we click on submitt button it should generation validation errors but currently i am not getting  error message

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but let's start at the beginning, Your HTML is invalid, so trying to get validation of items inside of a table with a `submit` button isn't worth looking at until you are using forms and tables properly.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you posted the rendered HTML after the server-side processing  has completed.

Comment: so,can you show me that how should be my form tag which i should use because this is MVC

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form